# Shortcut in Visual Studio to open solution in Windows file explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio (currently using 2013) to open the solution (or a project) in the Windows file explorer?

Currently, I normally have to open up the Solution Explorer, right-click on my solution or a project and scroll down to 'Open Folder in File Explorer', but this becomes a time consuming task as I have to do it often (TortoiseGit not integrated with my IDE).

Comment: Just want to note that there is a new much more elegant answer for VS2017 below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An improvement over @Walt_Ritscher's answer I found was to assign a keyboard shortcut to the **File.OpenContainingFolder**.

Instead of having to first select a project or solution from the solution project I can simply press a desired keyboard shortcut while any file is in focus (without having to open the Solution Explorer) and it will open the file location in Windows Explorer. This saves time if the focus in my solution explorer is on a file deep in the structure of my solution explorer since I don't have to scroll all the way back up to select a project/solution before hitting the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I think this binding isn’t included in a vanilla installation and comes from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio which is included in the PPT https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can add your own keyboard shortcut to open the folder.

Open the **Tools/Options/Keyboard** dialog.  In the **Show Commands Containing** textbox, type **OpenFolderIn** and you will see the **OpenFolderInFileExplorer** command.  Select the command, then assign a shortcut key. Move your cursor to the **Press shortcut keys** textbox.then press your desired key combination.  In my example I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>.  Be sure and click the **Assign** button to memorize the shortcut key

Press OK and you're done.

[image]

Comment: This is an improvement over my current process but I found it only works when I have actually selected a project or solution from the Solution Explorer, which still often requires a bit of scrolling when the solution explorer focus is on a file deep in the file structure of a project.

Comment: After setting this shortcut and the file explorer opens, just press backspace till your at the top level directory.  This works well for me.

Comment: that's a nice little shortcut actually, I had a tendency to click back once I reached file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio **vs2017**:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: For me this just appears to open the default Visual Studio repository folder, e.g. [User]/source/repos, which doesn't seem useful for what is wanted here.

Comment: On VS 2019 it dropped me into my solution folder under the repos folder.