# How to access current project solution via shortcut?

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to open the current project folder in visual studio, for example, some shortcut that allows me to do this. If I can't access via shortcut, how can I open the current solution in visual studio?

It is very annoying every time I want to access the current folder of my solution, having to manually open the directory

> C:/users/my_user/source/ repos/my_project/my_project_folder/bin/debug/

How can I easily access my project folder?

Comment: What are you asking, how to open a File Explorer window to the location of an item from the Solution Explorer? Isn't that part of the right-click menu? Or you could use [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter).

Comment: Or dupe of this question if you're after a _keyboard_ shortcut. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564879/shortcut-in-visual-studio-to-open-solution-in-windows-file-explorer

Comment: I want to open the debug folder, where I put all the files

Comment: Click the "Show all files" button in the Solution explorer, then right click the "bin" entry that appeared.